# WCF MSMQ Duplicate Messages Received from Transactional Queue With Multiple Receivers

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation-4, msmq, msdtc, distributed-transactions

I am experiencing a problem where a message from a transactional MSMQ queue, in rare occasions, is received twice.

Here is my setup (3 Windows 2008 R2 x64 Servers):

- MSMQ Server hosting private queues. They are configured to be transactional.
- 2 Servers hosting Workflows (WF4) receiving messages from the remote private queues on the MSMQ server via WCF.

  - Each queue has 2 receivers, 1 receiver per server. I expect that when one server pulls a message from the queue, this message cannot be processed again.
  - Messages are received transactionally (TransactionScopeRequired = true)
  - netMsmqBinding for receivers have `exactlyOnce="true"`
  - Each received message triggers the creation of a workflow instance. I am using a custom WorkflowHostingEndpoint, so I can set the workflow ID based on the contents of the message.

Sometimes the duplicate messages occur on only one of the servers, sometimes the duplicate messages occur across each of the two servers. This only occurs when there is a large volume of messages to process, and the duplicate messages are always received within a small time frame (usually < 200ms).

I can detect that a message is received twice because each message contains a unique GUID, which is used as a primary key for an insert into a database. When a message is received twice, I see primary key violation errors in the log file.

I turned on the WCF service model and message tracing and saw that the message was received twice with two different distributed transactions. In this case, this happened on the same server.

```
2012-08-16T08:31:18.4874394Z: Thread 210: Message Log Trace (message contains unique GUID 43df02cc-79c7-48ca-995f-175c22fb9e59)
2012-08-16T08:31:18.4874394Z: Thread 210: The transaction '69acc04f-4853-4680-bc13-3855f5b844d4:3782' was received for operation 'CreateWorkflow' from a transacted transport, such as MSMQ.
2012-08-16T08:31:18.6434444Z: Thread 207: Message Log Trace (message contains unique GUID 43df02cc-79c7-48ca-995f-175c22fb9e59)
2012-08-16T08:31:18.6434444Z: Thread 207: The transaction '69acc04f-4853-4680-bc13-3855f5b844d4:3789' was received for operation 'CreateWorkflow' from a transacted transport, such as MSMQ.
```

What can cause this to occur, and how do I prevent this from occurring?

**Update:** Here's the relevant code I'm using for sending messages. How I'm sending messages should not affect how messages are received, right? Could it be that opening a TransactionScope at the sender side will create a distributed transaction between the sender and receiver? This is really not the intention of this.

```
private static readonly ChannelFactory<IWorkflowCreation> _channelFactory = 
    new ChannelFactory<IWorkflowCreation>(new NetMsmqBinding(NetMsmqSecurityMode.None));

private void StartWorkflow(EndpointAddress address, WorkflowData data)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var client = _channelFactory.CreateChannel(address);
        using ((IClientChannel)client)
        {
            client.CreateWorkflow(data);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Please post the code that is sending the messages.